# Сборщик мусора и метод finalize в Java

Tags: java, сборщик-мусора

Из одной статьи

> Сборщик очистит финализированный объект за два шага: в первый выполниться finalize, а во второй соберется.

И так вопросы

1. Когда сборщик встречает финализированный объект он сначало отправляет его на очередь. И код в методе finalize выполняется уже в очереди. Когда метод выполнится он станет доступен сборщику и уничтожится при следующей сборке. Я правильно понял?
2. Stop the world действует на поток Finalizer?

Comment: Спасибо за нормальное оформление вопроса :)

Comment: Спасибо, за хороший ответ)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, вы правы - после выполнения метода `finalize()` объект должен быть повторно собран сборщиком мусора (и это считается серьезной проблемой метода `finalize()` - он мешает сборщику мусора освобождать память).

К слову, не обязательно объект будет доступен для сборки сразу же - метод `finalize()` может сохранить куда-нибудь ссылку на объект. Подобная ситуация называется "возрождением" объекта и, вообще говоря, считается антипаттерном. Главная проблема такого трюка - в том, что "возродить" объект можно только 1 раз.

---

Stop the world безусловно действует на поток Finalizer, поскольку это такой же поток как и все остальные.